# Basic Weld example with Embedded Tomcat not working

Tags: java, tomcat, weld, tomcat10, embedded-tomcat

I am trying to use Weld with Embedded Tomcat (10.1.5) using a basic example and settings from official [weld docs](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#environments).

**This weld injection with same code works fine with Tomcat on Eclipse.**

However, on Embedded Tomcat, the **injected bean is always null**. If I try to lookup BeanManager using JNDI it throws this error:

```java
//code
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
bm = (BeanManager) ((Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("BeanManager");
```

```
Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: WELD-001300: Unable to locate BeanManager
```

Added BeanManager entries to context.xml, web.xml, and empty beans.xml to WEB-INF.

gradle dependency:

```
implementation group: 'org.jboss.weld.servlet', name: 'weld-servlet-core', version: '5.1.0.Final'
```

main class:

```java
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

// declare an alternate location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir:
File additionWebInfClasses = new File("build/classes/java/main/");
WebResourceRoot webResourceRoot = new StandardRoot(ctx);
webResourceRoot.addPreResources(
        new DirResourceSet(webResourceRoot, "/WEB-INF/classes", additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));

ctx.addApplicationListener(Listener.class.getName());

tomcat.enableNaming();
tomcat.getConnector();
tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

What is the issue here? What extra setting is needed to use Weld with Embedded Tomcat ?

There is a curious difference in Weld startup logs too:

```
// Embedded Tomcat
Jan 26, 2023 11:50:56 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle initialize

// Tomcat with Eclipse
Jan 26, 2023 11:56:43 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.TomcatContainer initialize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Weld example was missing setResources() call which is needed to initialize this properly.

```
...
WebResourceRoot webResourceRoot = new StandardRoot(ctx);
webResourceRoot.addPreResources(
        new DirResourceSet(webResourceRoot, "/WEB-INF/classes", additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));

// this was missing 
ctx.setResources(webResourceRoot);
...
```

This is also easy to miss due to lack of documentation on embedded Tomcat.